# CAML Query on a SharePoint list is returning the ID and the value - how to just get the value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, caml, spservices

This question is about a SharePoint List. The code is using the SPServices, jQuery, and JavaScript.

Some fields for the columns are lookup fields, and I am getting both the ID and the value of the field.  Is there  a way to filter this out so that I am only getting the value without the ID?

For example, for the AssignedTo field the query returns values such as "91;#Doe, John" and "103;#Doe, Jane" where as what I need to see is "Doe, John", "Doe, Jane", etc.

Any advice on how to fix this would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

This is the CAML query segment of the code:

```
function loadPrioritizedList() {
        $("#tasksUL").empty();
        $().SPServices({
            operation: "GetListItems",    
            webURL: myURL,
            listName: targetListName,
            CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Priority_x0020_Number' /><FieldRef Name='Edit_x0020_Link' /><FieldRef Name='Priority' /><FieldRef Name='Top_x0020_Item_x003f_' /><FieldRef Name='Purpose' /><FieldRef Name='Item_x002d_Task_x0020_Order' /><FieldRef Name='Mode' /><FieldRef Name='Work_x0020_Status' /><FieldRef Name='DueDate' /><FieldRef Name='Task_x0020_Type' /><FieldRef Name='DAK_x0020_Date' /><FieldRef Name='DAK_x0020_No' /><FieldRef Name='AssignedTo' /><FieldRef Name='Money_x0020_Estimate' /><FieldRef Name='ItemStatus' /><FieldRef Name='Assign_x0020_Date' /></ViewFields>",
            CAMLQuery: '<Query>' +
    "<Where><IsNull><FieldRef Name=Assign_x0020_Date' /></IsNull></Where>" +
            '<OrderBy>' +
            '<FieldRef Name="Priority_x0020_Number" />' +
            '</OrderBy>' +
            '</Query>', 
        CAMLRowLimit: listrowlimit,  
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
            $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
                var tdHtml = "<tr class='sortable_row' id=" + $(this).attr("ows_ID") + ">";
                tdHtml = tdHtml + "<td style=\"width:60px;\">" + PriorityFormat($(this).attr("ows_Priority_x0020_Number"));  + "</td>";
                tdHtml = tdHtml + '<td style=\"width:49px;\"><a href=\"'+($(this).attr("ows_Edit_x0020_Link")).split(", ")[1] + '\">' + ($(this).attr("ows_Edit_x0020_Link")).split(", ")[1] + '</a></td>';
                tdHtml = tdHtml + "<td style=\"width:83px;\">" + $(this).attr("ows_Priority") + "</td>";
                tdHtml = tdHtml + "<td style=\"width:63px;\">" + TopItem($(this).attr("ows_Top_x0020_Item_x003f_")) + "</td>";
                tdHtml = tdHtml + "<td style=\"width:300px;\">" + StringChk($(this).attr("ows_Purpose")) + "</td>";
                tdHtml = tdHtml + "<td style=\"width:125px;\">" + StringChk($(this).attr("ows_Item_x002d_Task_x0020_Order")) + "</td>";                     
                tdHtml = tdHtml + "<td style=\"width:40px;\">" + StringChk($(this).attr("ows_Mode")) + "</td>";
                tdHtml = tdHtml + "<td style=\"width:75px;\">" + StringChk($(this).attr("ows_Task_x0020_Type")) + "</td>";
                tdHtml = tdHtml + "<td style=\"width:150px;\">" + StringChk($(this).attr("ows_Work_x0020_Status")) + "</td>";
                tdHtml = tdHtml + "<td style=\"width:100px;\">" + FormatDate($(this).attr("ows_DueDate")) + "</td>";
                tdHtml = tdHtml + "<td style=\"width:100px;\">" + FormatDate($(this).attr("ows_DAK_x0020_Date")) + "</td>";
                tdHtml = tdHtml + "<td style=\"width:100px;\">" + StringChk($(this).attr("ows_DAK_x0020_No")) + "</td>";
                tdHtml = tdHtml + "<td style=\"width:300px;\">" + StringChk($(this).attr("ows_AssignedTo")) + "</td>";
                tdHtml = tdHtml + "<td style=\"width:125px;\">" + $(this).attr("ows_Money_x0020_Estimate") + "</td>";
                tdHtml = tdHtml + "<td style=\"width:75px;\">" + StringChk($(this).attr("ows_ItemStatus")) + "</td>";
                tdHtml = tdHtml + "<td style=\"width:100px;\">" + FormatDate($(this).attr("ows_Assign_x0020_Date")) + "</td>";
                tdHtml = tdHtml + "</tr>";
                $("#tasksUL").append(tdHtml);
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my [framework](https://github.com/Aymkdn/SharepointPlus/blob/master/sharepointplus-3.0.4.js#L421) I use this function (I changed it a bit to make it independant):

```
/**
@name cleanResult
@function
@description clean a string returned by a GET (remove ";#" and "string;#" and null becomes "")
@param {String} str The string to clean
@param {String} [separator=";"] When it's a list we may want to have a different output (see examples)
@return {String} the cleaned string

@example
cleanResult("15;#Paul"); // -> "Paul"
cleanResult("string;#Paul"); // -> "Paul"
cleanResult(";#Paul;#Jacques;#Aymeric;#"); // -> "Paul;Jacques;Aymeric"
cleanResult(";#Paul;#Jacques;#Aymeric;#", ", "); // -> "Paul, Jacques, Aymeric"
*/
function cleanResult(str,separator) {
      if (str===null || typeof str==="undefined") return "";
      return (typeof str==="string"?str.replace(/;#[0-9]+;#/g,separator).replace(/^[0-9]+;#/,"").replace(/^;#|;#$/g,"").replace(/;#/g,separator).replace(/string;#/,""):str);
    }
```

Comment: this worked brilliantly!  Thank you very much for all the answers you have been providing to my questions lately.  It has been of enormous help to my project.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way SharePoint returns the value.  I would just use a regular expression to replace the value

```
var newValue = value.replace(/^\d+;#/,"");
```

This will look at the beginning of the string for a number followed by a semicolon and hashmark, and replace it with nothing.

Using your value above

```
var value = "91;#Doe"
var newValue = value.replace(/^\d+;@/,"");
```

will remove 91;# and assign Doe to newValue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regular expression as suggeted by Robbert or you can simply split the returned output value using the `;#`

In this way you can get the value in an array 
For example

you can do something like this

```
string[] words = value.Split(';#');

string NewValue = words[1];
```

Comment: That works well too.  Just make sure that ;# isn't anywhere else in the original string.

Comment: The question is for JavaScript ;-)